# Передать данные из одного $lookup в другой

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Есть aggregate-запрос, включающий в себя два `$lookup`:

```js
[{
    $match: {
      id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {      // 1
      from: 'blogs',
      as: 'blog',
      pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,      // *           Отсюда
          name: 1,
          articles: 1
        },
      }, {
        $match: {
          articles: {
            $in: [id]
          }
        }
      }, {
        $unset: 'articles'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {      // 2
      from: 'users',
      as: 'user',
      pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,
          user_name: 1,
          picture: 1
        },
      }, {
        $match: {
          blogs: {
            $in: [...]      // Передать сюда
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

Как можно передать поле из первого во второй (поле отмечено `*`)?

Comment: Ассоциация - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256297/pass-data-from-one-lookup-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте let: `{"blogIds": "$blog.id"}`

и в процессе используйте `$$blogIds`

```js
$lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    as: 'user',
    let: { "blogIds": "$blog.id" }
    pipeline: [{ ... }]
}
```